# Where can I see the exact row count of a table in pgAdmin III?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Where can I see the exact row count of a table in pgAdmin III?

I know where to find the approximate row count:

[image]

I am also aware I can `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table`. But I want to know whether the exact row count can be found somewhere in pgAdmin III's GUI, in the same way we can query the top 100 rows.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two lines below the estimate you highlighted we can see:

```
Rows (counted)  not counted
```

Right-click and choose `Count` from the context-menu to get the current count right there. Be aware that the count is only accurate in the moment it is taken.
pgAdmin does not count rows in big tables ([because that can be expensive](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting)) unless it's told to do so. There is a setting in the `Options`:

```
Count rows if estimated less than [2000]
```

Replace the default 2000 if you want a different limit. Details in the manual here:

http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/options-browser.html